# Zero filling attributes using ArcPy/Python?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am just learning python and I need to convert a 2 digit numeric attribute in a table to a 2 digit zero-filled attribute in a script.

For example, 9 needs to be 09.

Comment: If your field is numeric field you will have to create a new text field to do this.  Also, what version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: Thanks I am using 10.0 and the zfill worked for me. I'm an old dog learning new tricks much apprecaited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [zfill() help in python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) or this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/python-nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string). As @artwork mentions, you must convert the value to string and make the calculation. You can use zfill() inside the cursor, or use as an expression in the [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) tool.

Comment: Good suggestion! `n = 4` or `n = 40` followed by `print str(n).zfill(2)` will return the correctly padded values.

Comment: Here is the syntax to use in a Calculate Field expression: `str(!NUM_ID!).zfill(2)` -- where NUM_ID is your source field.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (if using ArcGIS 10.1, for ArcGIS 10 you will have to use this [update cursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000)):

1. First add a empty text field, e.g. textField to your feature class or shapefile.
2. You can run the below code in PythonWin, ArcMap, or ArcCatalog Python window.  Or put it into a .py file and call it from a user created toolbox script tool.

**Updated:**

```
    import arcpy

    fc = "C://temp//Default.gdb//myLayer" # update to your layer
    fields = ('numField', 'textField') # put your numeric and text field here
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] <= 9:
                row[1] = '0' + str(row[0])
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if the number is already 2 digits (10 - 99)? I think you will end up with a padded '010' or '099' when the user actually wants '10' and '99' if the number is already 2 digits long?

Comment: Updated my answer, thx.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a value and you need to make it 2 digit value, have a look:

```
import sys

inputValue = sys.argv[1]
checkValue = int(inputValue)

if checkValue <= 9:
    inputValue = '0' + inputValue
print inputValue
```

input->output:
2 -> 02,
20 -> 20

Comment: While this will work, the built-in functions `zfill` or `rjust` make much more sense.